# Using Mouse Drag To Control Background Position

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to use the 'mouse's drag' to drag a background's position around, inside a box.

The CSS:

```
.filmmakers #map {    
   width : 920px;    
   height : 500px;    
   margin-top : 50px;    
   margin-left : 38px;    
   border : 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);    
   cursor : move;    
   overflow : hidden;    
   background-image : url('WorldMap.png');    
   background-repeat : no-repeat;    
}
```

The html:

```
<div id = "map" src = "WorldMap.png" onmousedown = "MouseMove(this)"> </div>
```

The Javascript:

```
function MouseMove (e) {    
   var x = e.clientX;    
   var y = e.clientY;    
    e.style.backgroundPositionX = x + 'px';    
    e.style.backgroundPositionY = y + 'px';    
    e.style.cursor = "move";    
}
```

Nothing happens, no errors, no warnings, nothing... I have tried lots of things: an absolutely positioned image inside a div (you can guess why that didn't work), A draggable div inside a div with a background image, a table with drag and drop, and finally I tried this:

```
function MouseMove () {    
    e.style.backgroundPositionX = 10 + 'px';    
    e.style.backgroundPositionY = 10 + 'px';    
    e.style.cursor = "move";    
}
```

This works, but its not relative to the mouse's position, `pageX` and `pageY` don't work either.

A live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VRvUB/224/

P.S: whatever your idea is, please don't write it in JQuery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your question I understood you needed help implementing the actual "dragging" behavior. I guess not. Anyway, here's the results of my efforts: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/VRvUB/236/

The drag only happens when the mouse button, and.. well, it behaves as I think you might want it to. Just see the fiddle if you haven't =)

Here's the code for those who want to see it here:

```
var AttachDragTo = (function () {
    var _AttachDragTo = function (el) {
        this.el = el;
        this.mouse_is_down = false;

        this.init();
    };

    _AttachDragTo.prototype = {
        onMousemove: function (e) {
            if ( !this.mouse_is_down ) return;
            var tg = e.target,
                x = e.clientX,
                y = e.clientY;

            tg.style.backgroundPositionX = x - this.origin_x + this.origin_bg_pos_x + 'px';
            tg.style.backgroundPositionY = y - this.origin_y + this.origin_bg_pos_y + 'px';
        },

        onMousedown: function(e) {
            this.mouse_is_down = true;
            this.origin_x = e.clientX;
            this.origin_y = e.clientY;
        },

        onMouseup: function(e) {
            var tg = e.target,
                styles = getComputedStyle(tg);

            this.mouse_is_down = false;
            this.origin_bg_pos_x = parseInt(styles.getPropertyValue('background-position-x'), 10);
            this.origin_bg_pos_y = parseInt(styles.getPropertyValue('background-position-y'), 10);
        },

        init: function () {
            var styles = getComputedStyle(this.el);
            this.origin_bg_pos_x = parseInt(styles.getPropertyValue('background-position-x'), 10);
            this.origin_bg_pos_y = parseInt(styles.getPropertyValue('background-position-y'), 10);

            //attach events
            this.el.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onMousedown.bind(this), false);
            this.el.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseup.bind(this), false);
            this.el.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMousemove.bind(this), false);
        }
    };

    return function ( el ) {
        new _AttachDragTo(el);
    };
})();


/*** IMPLEMENTATION ***/
//1. Get your element.
var map = document.getElementById('map');
//2. Attach the drag.
AttachDragTo(map);
​
```

Comment: This one works better so i'll mark it correct and up-vote, Thank you so much JOPLO! for taking the time to create a wonderfully coded example, thank you also for your kind time! Cheers and have a great day ! :)

Comment: No problem ;) Had fun doing it.

Comment: alright Cheers! :) if ever you need anything coded m8, I am a wiz with css!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't working because **you are passing the element "map" to your `MouseMove` function, and using it as both an event object and an element**. You can fix this painlessly by using JavaScript to assign your event handler rather than HTML attributes:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('map').onmousemove = function (e) {
    // the first parameter (e) is automatically assigned an event object
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;

    // The context of this is the "map" element
    this.style.backgroundPositionX = x + 'px';
    this.style.backgroundPositionY = y + 'px';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VRvUB/229/

**The downside of this approach** is that the `backgroundPositionX` and `backgroundPositionY` style properties are [not supported in all browsers](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y).

You mention *"an absolutely positioned image inside a div"* which is probably the more compatible solution for this. To make this setup work, you need to set the `position` of the outer element to `relative`, which makes `absolute` child elements use its bounds as zero.

```
<div id="map">
    <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#map {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#map img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Here it is applied to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/VRvUB/232/

Answer (score 2):

This works 100%
**Vanilla Javascript**

```js
document.getElementById('image').onmousemove = function (e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    this.style.backgroundPositionX = -x + 'px';
    this.style.backgroundPositionY = -y + 'px';
    this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://i.ibb.co/vhL5kH2/image-14.png)';
}
document.getElementById('image').onmouseleave = function (e) {
    this.style.backgroundPositionX = 0 + 'px';
    this.style.backgroundPositionY = 0 + 'px';
    this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://i.ibb.co/Ph9MCB2/template.png)';
}
```

```css
.container {
   max-width: 670px;
   height: 377px;
}
#image {
   max-width: 670px;
   height: 377px;
   cursor: crosshair;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/Ph9MCB2/template.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <div id="image">
     </div>
</div>
```