# Full background image on mobile, move around entire image by dragging view port

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have an image of a map[image]

On mobile I would like to be taken to a specific part of that map (say Africa) and move around the whole map by pinching.

My CSS is here:

```
main {
  background-image: url("map.jpg");
  /* Full height */
  height: 100vh; 
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

However on mobile I get this:
[image]

I cannot move around the map by pinching. How can I do this?

You can [simulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456764/how-to-simulate-pinch-zoom-in-google-chrome) dragging across the view port on Chrome by hitting shift + mouse click.

Make sure you test on mobile view on devtools.

Comment: what you thing it's possible `img size like 4 * 4` and you `div size is 4 * 8` if any possibility you can use `background-size:100% 100%` but img  looks like stretchy

Comment: @lalitbhakuni interesting. is there anyway i can keep the aspect ratio same, but just show a small part of the image on mobile? basically i don't need to see the entire image at once but i should be able to move around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i thinks you need `java script` for moving background img

I have find the solution.

**thanks to @banzomaikaka ** [Using Mouse Drag To Control Background Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367959/using-mouse-drag-to-control-background-position)

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/VRvUB/854/

Comment: Thanks dude! It's unfortunate I may need javascript but whatever works I guess. I will keep this question open for a couple hours to see if there is a more elegant solution. thx for contribution.

Comment: There is not... You need JS... Not possible without it... CSS doesn't allow for the conditional logic you need... meaning if(condition){do something...}

Answer (score -1):

You need this meta tag in the head of the HTML file:
Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.5, maximum-scale=12.0, minimum-scale=.25, user-scalable=yes"/>
```

Comment: And you still can't pinch zoom?

Comment: Try this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.5, maximum-scale=12.0, minimum-scale=.25, user-scalable=yes"/>

Comment: nah no fix. i can pinch and zoom. but i can't pinch around the whole image. the image is cropped to part of the whole map (as per second picture). i can pinch around if i zoom in the already cropped picture. thx

Comment: Ok, I understand your issue now... Sorry, can't do what you want with just CSS... You need conditional logic... How familiar are you with JavaScript? If none at all - can't help you...